# Traverse upwards through nested ajax accordion web controls; Type checking and FindControl

Tags: ajax, asp.net-3.5, accordion, findcontrol, typechecking

I have nested ajax accordion web controls (nested 3 deep or sometimes 4 deep) and I am trying to find a nested accordion's parent accordion. I want to do this when either of the deep-most accordions becomes databound.

```
protected void grandChildAccordion_ItemDataBound(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AccordionItem.ItemType == AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionItemType.Header)
    {
         // find parent accordion
    }
}
```

Sometimes the parent accordion will be at e.AccordionItem.Parent.Parent.Parent level or  e.AccordionItem.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent level.

So, how do I check if `e.AccordionItem.Parent` equals `AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel` "type"?

**The** (not-so-elegant) **Solution:** I have nested accordions, the deep-most accordion levels contains lists of documents, and each accordion header has a label showing a count of documents nested within it. Starting from the deep-most accordion level where I get a count of documents, I traverse up the nested accordions and find each accordion header, allowing me to find their doc count label and add a value to it..  hope this helps someone:

```
// Save doc count. It will be displayed in doc count label within current accordion header, and the value will then be added to the doc count of each parent accordion's header.
int curDocCount = qcDocsBO.FetchQCDocumentCountByProjectID(SessionHandler.ProjectID, qcDocsBO.LSDItemID);
lblDocCount.Text = curDocCount.ToString();

// A deep-most accordion has just been DataBound. Start traversing upwards through nested accordions, adding the doc count to each parent accordion header's doc count label.
AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion curAccordion = sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion;
AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane parentAccCP = curAccordion.Parent.Parent.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane;
if (parentAccCP == null)
    parentAccCP = curAccordion.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane;
while (parentAccCP != null)
{
    Label parentDocCountLabel = (Label)parentAccCP.FindControl("lblDocCount");
    if (parentDocCountLabel.Text == "")
        parentDocCountLabel.Text = "0";
    parentDocCountLabel.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(parentDocCountLabel.Text) + curDocCount).ToString();

    AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane nextParentAccCP = parentAccCP.Parent.Parent.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane;

    if (nextParentAccCP == null)
        nextParentAccCP = parentAccCP.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane;
    if (nextParentAccCP == null)
        nextParentAccCP = parentAccCP.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane;
    if (nextParentAccCP == null)
        nextParentAccCP = parentAccCP.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane;
    if (nextParentAccCP != null)
        parentAccCP = nextParentAccCP;
    else
        parentAccCP = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do type checks using the `is` keyword or safe cast using the `as` keyword.

Consider the following:

```
if(e.AccordionItem.Parent is AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel) {
   ...
}
```

or this

```
var accordion = e.AccordionItem.Parent as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel;
if(accordion != null) {
   ...
}
```

`accordion` is null if the safe cast wasn't successful.

Using either or both of these techniques, you can iterate upwards in the hierarchy and stop when you encounter the type you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this helped fill a big gap in my knowledge of c#!

Comment: Always nice to help. Also know that the `is` and `as` keywords evaluates upwards in the inheritance chain. Example: `e.AccordionItem.Parent is AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel` might be true but `e.AccordionItem.Parent is WebControl` might be true as well. It's basically standard OOP thinking - a Monkey *is* a Primate but it is also an Animal. To check *exact* type, use the `GetType` method.